# function parameter as json key

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not a JSON god by any stretch of the imagination, but I'm not understanding why this isn't working, and what I need to do to make it work.  I've searched around for a while now and most likely my problem is I don't know the right keywords to search for to solve this.  I'm wanting to call a function and, within that function, create a JSON object so I can store it in an IndexedDB "table", like so:

```
UpdateSettingsValue("initialized", true);

function UpdateSettingsValue(key, value){
    var tx = db.transaction(["settings"], "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("settings");
    var trans = {
        key:value
    }
    var request = store.add(trans);
}
```

This is creating an entry just fine, but it gets written as `{key: true}`.

So my question is how can I make it written as `{initialized: true}`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just initialize the `trans` variable by hand instead of using literal syntax:

```
function UpdateSettingsValue(key, value){
    var tx = db.transaction(["settings"], "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("settings");
    var trans = {};
    trans[key] = value;
    var request = store.add(trans);
}
```